# sorting dictionary in python by value where the keys are tuple

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

how can I  sort a dictionary in python by its value where the key is a tuple and after sorting based on value, how can I get back the corresponding key?
I have a dictionary like:

```
{(1,1): 25, (1,2): 36, (1,3): 21, (2,1): 45, (2,2): 87, (2,3): 70}
```

. I want to sort based on the values . The output should be :

```
{(1,3): 21, (1,1): 25, (1,2): 36, (2,1): 45, (2,3): 70, (2,2): 87}
```

Comment: Please post your sample code here

Comment: Sorting doesn't change the keys, so what is there to "get back"?

Comment: I have a dictionary like: { (1,1) : 25 , (1,2) : 36 , (1,3) :21 ,(2,1):45 ,(2,2): 87, (2,3) : 70}. I want to sort based on the values . The output should be : {(1,3):21 , (1,1):25 , (1,2):36 , (2,1):45 , (2,3):70, (2,2):87}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort a dictionary by its value like this:

```py
some_dict = {(1,1): 25, (1,2): 36, (1,3): 21, (2,1): 45, (2,2): 87, (2,3): 70}

sorted_dict = dict(sorted(some_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1]))

print(sorted_dict)
```

Output: `{(1, 3): 21, (1, 1): 25, (1, 2): 36, (2, 1): 45, (2, 3): 70, (2, 2): 87}`

---

You can then get the keys in order using

```py
print(list(sorted_dict.keys()))
```

Output: `[(1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 2)]`

Comment: Thanks for your response. You were so helpful. I have also another question and I hope you can help with that too. I am working with the Pyomo package(for mathematical modeling in python).I have a parameter defined as:  model.D=Param(model.t,model.i) .this is a multi dimensional parameter. t is for the range of time periods, i is for the the range of instances and D is the value of the demand. as I know parameters in pyomp are dictionary. I applied your code to sort this parameter by its value. I didn't get any error. but not the correct response by looking at the printed values.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer to this, try posting this in another question.

Comment: Thanks, I did. However, thank you for your time and response. you were helpful!